# Calendar event reminder times change on nexus4

Tags: calendar

I have an all day event a week away in the native calendar, and I set the reminder to 12 hours, so that it does not vibrate at midnight. However, it does. When I check it, I can see it is somehow changed to 24 hours. Non all day events behave the same, but being alarmed at 9AM is not as bothering.

This only happens, if I define the event and the reminder in the outlook calendar. It seems that Google Calendar Sync messes up the syncing. Any other reminder time gets synced fine.

Have you had this problem?
How do I avoid it?

Comment: Just for clarification: what "reminder app" are you talking about? There's an app with this name ("Calendar Event Reminder") on Google Play -- is it that? Or are you talking about the "native calendar"? Or any other calendar app?

Comment: Native calendar, edited the question accordingly.